# Implement custom comparitor for struct pointers

Tags: c++, comparison, stdmap

I am working on a custom graph data structure.  For simplicity, let's say it's represented as:

```
std::map<Node *, std::vector<Node *>>
```

where `Node *` is a custom data type, a struct.  I would like to pass in a custom pointer comparitor.  Namely,

```
std::map<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, order>
```

Let's say `Node` is:

What is the proper way to write a custom comparitor?  I have tried writing:

```
struct Graph {




    struct Node { 
        int component_idx;
        Eigen::Vector2d pos;

        struct order {
            bool operator()(const Node * a, const Node * b) const {
                return a->component_idx < b->component_idx;
            }

        };

    };

    std::map<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, Graph::Node::order> c_map;



};
```

However, passing `Node::order` to the map causes compile errors on declaring a map,

```
std::map<Graph::Node *, Graph::Node *, Graph::Node::order> node_map;
```

Error   C2664   'bool Graph::Node::order::operator ()(const Graph::Node *,const Graph::Node *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Graph::Node *const ' to 'const Graph::Node *'

Clearly this is a typing issue, but this is how the examples I have seen online do it, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.  Can somebody help me fix this example?

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Please edit your post with an example usage (of how *you* are using the comparator).

Comment: The code you presented here doesn't cause compile errors for me.

Comment: According to the error message, you defined the `operator()` as `bool order::operator()(Node *a, Node *b) const`, which is different from the code in your question.

Comment: @Galik I tried to simplify the example but maybe I oversimplified it.  I apologize.  I guess I will have to track down what caused the error.

Comment: @user650261 Why is the key in your map `Node*` instead of just `Node`?  If you're going to write a map comparator, you might as well have the key as a value type, not a pointer.

Comment: still, the above comment applies, you apparently wrote your operator taking non-const pointers, but a map key is necessarily const, so it won't work.

Comment: I am literally going to copy and paste my code to avoid any errors.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would not use copy/paste tbh :)

Comment: Sorry, I copy/pasted it and then tried to simplify it out to as minimal an example as possible, clearly I messed something up there.

Comment: I'm checking now, but I'm 90% sure that the error is actually unrelated and was a namespacing issue on my part (two graph representations and using one comparitor on the other by mistake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, as it turns out this was an unrelated error.  This is just a namespacing issue - I was referencing the wrong version of a similar method in another (similar) struct.  The code as posted works.